# how do addButton in grid admin magento2?

Tags: admin, magento2, grid

in grid admin magento2 i want add button new. how do it? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you cannot add a button in there.
All grids (that look like the one in your screenshot) use this template `Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid.phtml`.
Here is a section of the template:

```
<?php $countRecords = $block->getCollection()->getSize(); ?>
    <div class="admin__control-support-text">
        <span id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getHtmlId()) ?>-total-count" <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUiId('total-count') ?>>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $countRecords ?>
        </span>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('records found') ?>
        <span id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getHtmlId()) ?>_massaction-count"
              class="mass-select-info _empty"><strong data-role="counter">0</strong> <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('selected') ?></span></span>
    </div>
<?php if ($block->getPagerVisibility()): ?>
    <div class="admin__data-grid-pager-wrap">
   ....
    </div>
    ......
```

The code above displays the size of the collection displayed in the grid and then the pager immediately after. There is nothing between them.

If you want an additional button you need to modify the template.

Add this in your grid class

```
protected $_template='[Namespace]_[Module]::grid.phtml';
```

Then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/grid.phtml`. This should be a clone of `Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid.phtml`.
Then you can edit this template and insert you button(s) in the section I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

add below code way to create Grid as well buttons.

`Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Grid.php` file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml;


class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container
{

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_grid';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Vendor_Modulename';
        $this->_headerText = __('Slide Show Grid');
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Slideshow');
    }

}
```

and

`Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Grid;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
}
```

Comment: My block exteneds  Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended; 
i tried it. this not show button

Comment: @xanka, see my code updated. `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended` this class will extend only grid part `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container` this class will create buttons etc..

Comment: i edited question