# No 'Add Product' button - magento 2.0

Tags: products

Trying to add new product according to this article
http://blog.belvg.com/creating-a-simple-product-in-magento-2-0.html

However i don't have an 'Add Product' button
[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94095/how-do-addbutton-in-grid-admin-magento2/94110#94110 Maybe help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after a fresh installation.

I fixed it by clearing the **var/generation** folder of my magento2 installation, then everything went fine.